# Can't replace value upon condition?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I get an error 'list index out of range' but after checking the code I can't understand what's wrong.

Here are the data:

```
import numpy as np
proba_ex=[np.array([[0.00639649, 0.00251385, 0.00729689, 0.007919488, 0.00368546,
         0.00068663],
        [0.08320138, 0.04170561, 0.04755181, 0.42204733, 0.15220323,
         0.10432409]]),np.array([[0.14774831, 0.09566049, 0.30208335, 0.05015277, 0.10008666,
         0.06229035],
        [0.0573518 , 0.095365  , 0.11942169, 0.12236523, 0.21965485,
         0.11497026]])]


pred_data_ex=[np.array(['class3','class4']),np.array(['class1','class7'])]
```

Below is the code, what it does is:
If the condition with the comment below gives a result less than 0.1 it should replace the `pred_data_ex` with the word 'UNK'.

```
for x in proba_ex:
    pt=0.1
    for z in pred_data_ex:
        sproba=[]
    
        for i,p in enumerate(z):
            xa=-np.sort(-proba_ex[i])
            if xa[0][0]-xa[0][1]<pt:   #here is the condition
                pred_data_ex[i]=u'<UNK>'
```

When I run it I get:

```
  IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-21-fb2d5516c0db> in <module>
          6 
          7         for i,p in enumerate(z):
    ----> 8             xa=-np.sort(-proba_ex[i])
          9             print(xa)
         10           #  sproba.append(xa)
    
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

**EDIT:**
The end result should look like this for example:

The output of pred_data_ex should be something like:

```
[np.array(['UNK','class4']),np.array(['class1','UNK'])]
```

as you can see it replaces based on the condition described, the word 'UNK' when needed.

**EDIT 2**
explanation

@Yossi from your code the result is the following:

```
xa: [[0.00791949 0.00729689 0.00639649 0.00368546 0.00251385 0.00068663]
 [0.42204733 0.15220323 0.10432409 0.08320138 0.04755181 0.04170561]]
xa: [[0.30208335 0.14774831 0.10008666 0.09566049 0.06229035 0.05015277]
 [0.21965485 0.12236523 0.11942169 0.11497026 0.095365   0.0573518 ]]
xa: [[0.00791949 0.00729689 0.00639649 0.00368546 0.00251385 0.00068663]
 [0.42204733 0.15220323 0.10432409 0.08320138 0.04755181 0.04170561]]
xa: [[0.30208335 0.14774831 0.10008666 0.09566049 0.06229035 0.05015277]
 [0.21965485 0.12236523 0.11942169 0.11497026 0.095365   0.0573518 ]]
xa: [[0.00791949 0.00729689 0.00639649 0.00368546 0.00251385 0.00068663]
 [0.42204733 0.15220323 0.10432409 0.08320138 0.04755181 0.04170561]]
xa: [[0.30208335 0.14774831 0.10008666 0.09566049 0.06229035 0.05015277]
 [0.21965485 0.12236523 0.11942169 0.11497026 0.095365   0.0573518 ]]
xa: [[0.00791949 0.00729689 0.00639649 0.00368546 0.00251385 0.00068663]
 [0.42204733 0.15220323 0.10432409 0.08320138 0.04755181 0.04170561]]
xa: [[0.30208335 0.14774831 0.10008666 0.09566049 0.06229035 0.05015277]
 [0.21965485 0.12236523 0.11942169 0.11497026 0.095365   0.0573518 ]]
[array(['<UNK>', 'class4'], dtype='<U6'), array(['<UNK>', 'class7'], dtype='<U6')]
```

It looks that the result is incorrect because if you check the calculations it should give this:

```
[np.array(['UNK','class4']),np.array(['class1','UNK'])]
```

because:

```
0.00791949 -0.00729689<0.1
True (which makes it take the 'UNK' value)

0.42204733 -0.15220323<0.1
False

0.30208335 -0.14774831<0.1
False

0.21965485- 0.12236523<0.1
True (which makes it take the 'UNK' value)
```

therefore it should be:

```
[np.array(['UNK','class4']),np.array(['class1','UNK'])]
```

your result gives:

```
[array(['<UNK>', 'class4'], dtype='<U6'), array(['<UNK>', 'class7'], dtype='<U6')]
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: `i` is an index of `z`, so you should being doing `xa=-np.sort(-z[i])` or simply `xa=-np.sort(-p)` instead if that is indeed the logic you're pursuing.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @blhsing Thanks for answering. When  I type `xa=-np.sort(-z[i])` or `xa=-np.sort(-p)`, I get: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'`

Comment: I was just pointing out the obvious, that `i` should not be used as an index for `proba_ex`., since it is derived from an enumeration of `z`. The fact that you're getting an error with `xa=-np.sort(-p)` simply means that the logic of your code is flawed to begin with. You'd have to figure out the algorithm you want to pursue on your own since we don't know anything about the context of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some debugging I found it, You change the variable `pred_data_ex` inside the inner loop, such that in some point `z` is larger than 2 elements (You actually loop over a string with more than 2 characters, take a look at `p`).
That's why you access the proba_ex over the list size.

here is the additions that made me figure it out (several prints), take a look at the value of `z`, `p` and `i` along the loop's iterations:

```
import numpy as np

proba_ex=[np.array([[0.00639649, 0.00251385, 0.00729689, 0.007919488, 0.00368546,
         0.00068663],
        [0.08320138, 0.04170561, 0.04755181, 0.42204733, 0.15220323,
         0.10432409]]),np.array([[0.14774831, 0.09566049, 0.30208335, 0.05015277, 0.10008666,
         0.06229035],
        [0.0573518 , 0.095365  , 0.11942169, 0.12236523, 0.21965485,
         0.11497026]])]


pred_data_ex=[np.array(['class3','class4']),np.array(['class1','class7'])]

for x in proba_ex:
    pt=0.1
    for j,z in enumerate(pred_data_ex):
        sproba=[]
        if not isinstance(z,str):
            for i,p in enumerate(z):
                xa=-np.sort(-proba_ex[i])
                print("xa: " + str(xa))
                if xa[0][0]-xa[0][1]<pt:   #here is the condition
                    pred_data_ex[j][i]=u'<UNK>'

print(pred_data_ex)
```

the difference between first and second element after sorting proba_ex is larger than 0.1 for the second array and smaller for the first array. which correspondly to your code mean that the first element of each dual elements in pred-data_ex will replaced to '' as you wish, not as you said that expected.

my output:

```
[array(['<UNK>', 'class4'], dtype='<U6'), array(['<UNK>', 'class7'], dtype='<U6')]
```

which make sense as long as the first array feet the condition and the second don't

Comment: What change is needed to work then?

Comment: Can you tell me please how to solve it?

Comment: edited, now this is without the error. pay attention that i dont fully understand the purpose of your program. but I avoided the error by discard the cases of loop over the indices that already replaced (they are of type `str`)

Comment: ok, I will study it and let you know and mark your answer too if it is alright.thnks

Comment: I have done an edit in my question to further assist you with the logic of the code.
Maybe you are close to a solution but I don't know what is going on.
Please check the edit I made and see if you know what is needed.

Comment: as you can see my answer was not match to your expected. I think that ot your explanations wasn't so clear, or you has mistaken expected. If it still not feet, feel free to keep asking but privately

Comment: very close it seems but something must still be wrong with the way it calculates, see my second edit to see why it is not correct.

Comment: after several clarifications, I think that this is the right one. still feel free to ask more, but in the chat and not here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221732/discussion-between-saz-and-yossi-levi).